# Typo in 'off-topic' description

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, flags

The description for an off-topic close vote / flag has a typo:

[image: Typo]

The word "*puzzle*" should be plural. It should read:

> This question does not appear to be about programming puzzles or code golf within the scope defined in the help center.